# TYPO3 V9 - EXT:news - show custom news type in list view

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

## Custom News type in default list Plugin

I am using **TYPO3 V9** and **EXT:news 7.3.1**

I added a custom `news type` and I can create news records with this type just as described in https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Tutorials/ExtendNews/AddCustomType/Index.html

But when I add a list plugin, then it does not show me the records of this new news type in the list view.

I can create a custom plugin and render the list by my own, but somehow thought it should be possible with the default news plugin? Is it?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you have done so far. But don't you think you can use `sys_category` in the `tx_news` for your functionality instead of extending it?

Comment: No, the news types are used to give the user different versions with different sets of TCA fields. news comes with 3 types out of the box and I added more. sys_categorys cant alter the fields that the user gets, they just filter the results.